# pandas.read_html() returning errors

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda3

I'm following a pandas course online and see the instructor easily import a table with:

```
import pandas as pd
url= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Summer_Olympics_medal_table'
pd.read_html(url,header=0)
```

When I try it, I get errors:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEpJ8.png)

Is this an Anaconda issue? I had a friend try it from his computer and it worked just fine.

Comment: I cannot replicate the error as it works fine for me. `SSLCertificationError` indicates an internet access issue on your end.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to 7shoe pointing out an internet issue, I decided to use a VPN. This fixed the errors.

Comment: Side comment, if you have certificate errors, make sure you're not undergoing a MITM attack